# Connection error while trying to connect nodejs to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2012

I am new to node.js and need help connecting with SQL server

I have the following node.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'Amtex123',
        server: 'LAPTOP-7ACI67I5', 
        database: 'TData',
        port: 1433
    };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);
    enter code here
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from credentials', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);  
           });
         });
      });
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

I am getting an error messages

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to LAPTOP-7ACI67I5:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
>
> at Connection.tedious.once.err (C:\Projects\nodejs\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>   at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
>   at Connection.socketError (C:\Projects\nodejs\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:869:14)
>   at C:\Projects\nodejs\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:739:25
>   at SequentialConnectionStrategy.connect (C:\Projects\nodejs\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:153:9)
>   at Socket.onError (C:\Projects\nodejs\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:169:16)
>   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>   at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>   code: 'ESOCKET',**

I checked various solution to and

1. all SQL Services are running
2. TCP/IP is enabled

Comment: I got it working. Changed the TCP Dynamic ports to blank (instead of zero)

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?